# Error while installing SonarQube for Code Analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Hi I am trying to install SonarQube and I am encountering the following error:

> WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11+ to run
>   jvm 1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11+ to run

I have installed Java JDK 12 from here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html

I have added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin` to my `PATH` of system environment variables

Also, I have enough space on my C:\ drive 195GB free and running the console as administrator.

Can someone help what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you open a terminal (cmd / bash) and type: java -version. Then check it's output.

Comment: java version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my bad, I was mixing 32-bit and 64-bit versions. It works now.

Comment: Could you tell me where did you find the 32-bit version of SonarQube Community edition ?